# Releasing memory of multiple view controllers inside a scrollview

Tags: ios, memory, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, scrollview

I have an app the loaded many view controllers in a scroll view depending on the number of objects the user has in a tableview. So when I flip between the tableview and the scroll view, the number of view controllers in the scroll view changes according to how many objects the user has in the tableview.

I use the code in Apple's PageControl sample code to build the scroll view with many view controllers inside it, after some modification of course.

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page 
{
   if (page < 0) return;
   if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

   // replace the placeholder if necessary
   MainViewController *countdownController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
   if ((NSNull *)countdownController == [NSNull null]) 
   {

      id occasion = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:page];

      countdownController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
      [countdownController setOccasion:occasion];

      [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:countdownController];


      [countdownController release];

    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (nil == countdownController.view.superview) 
    {
      CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
      frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      countdownController.view.frame = frame;
      [scrollView addSubview:countdownController.view];
    }

}
```

The problem is the number of living view controllers (MainViewController here) keeps increasing when I flip between the table view and the scroll view (according to Instruments) even though I didn't add any new objects which causes memory problems of course.

I tried so many things in viewWillDisappear of the scroll view like:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{


    //test unloading all views
    //Remove all subviews
    [[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    //[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];


    //[viewControllers removeAllObjects];
    for (unsigned m = 0; m < [viewControllers count]; m++)
    {
     //[[viewControllers objectAtIndex:m] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)];

      [viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:m];
    }
 }
```

But it didn't work. 
Here is a recording of how the app works youtube.com/watch?v=5W8v_smZSog

And this is the viewWillAppear method of the scroll view:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    kNumberOfPages = [self.dataModel occasionCount];

    //update the eventsArray from the dataModel
    //Fill in the events Array with occasions form the data model
    for (unsigned r = 0; r < kNumberOfPages; r++)
    {
        Occasion* occasion = [self.dataModel occasionAtIndex:r];
        [eventsArray insertObject:occasion atIndex:r];
    }

     // view controllers are created lazily
     // in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on   demand
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
     }

    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    [controllers release];

    // a page is the width of the scroll view
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages,        scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
    pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
}
```

UPDATE: Video recording of Instruments http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1Rd2clvMQE&feature=youtube_gdata_player

And a screen shot showing the responsible caller:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I think it's unusual to put view controller views in a table view--what about using plain `UITableViewCell`s?

Comment: I'm not putting the view controllers in a tableview but in a scroll view. The number of these view controllers depends on the data in the table view.

Comment: same concept applies.. why not load a set of views and put those in your scroll view? You set it up so you have one view controller that owns the scroll view and subviews.

Comment: That's what I am doing and it's working fine. The problem is that memory isn't released after I release the view controllers. I verified that in instruments by checking the number of live view controllers and the memory that keeps increasing.

Comment: I am saying have _one view controller_, not multiple view controllers. In any case view controllers need to be notified when they are removed from a parent view controller AND their view needs to be removed from their superview.

Comment: Why aren't you using `ARC`? `ARC` will handle the problem!

Comment: @nielsbot that's what I'm trying to do. I'm removing the view controllers from their parent view and then removing their vies from the parent scroll view. But the dealloc of the view controllers is never called so the memory keeps increasing.

Comment: @MSgambel it's a one year old project so it's almost done and transitioning to ARC now would be a big hassle. While if I fix this memory leak, I'm ready to submit.

Comment: How much code is it? I moved a big project to ARC in 2 days.

Comment: I agree. There is a auto tool that helps you in the `Edit` menu at the top, and not only will it solve this problem, it will solve other problems that you may not even be aware of. You could easily convert it to `ARC` before this bounty even ends.

Comment: also, if you have more than 1 view controller, you're not doing what I suggested--I meant have just 1 single view controller that manages the scroll view and all contained views...

Comment: I have about 24 files. I'll look into converting to ARC if nothing else here works. @nielsbot I do have one view controller for the scroll view. This scroll view controller loads the other view controllers, one for each page. I put a video link at the end of the question.

Comment: ok if you still can't get it to work, use Instruments and use the allocation instrument. Turn on "track all allocations"... you will be able to see the stack trace for each retain/release/autorelease to every object in your app, including view controllers. That could help.

Comment: @nielsbot I did that (new video recording in the question) and I know that the `- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page ` is the responsible method.  But there are something I don't get here: In the `loadScrollViewWithPage` we check if the `viewControllers` array has a Null then we replace it with the newly created `MainViewController` named `countDownController` and increases the reference count by 1 so it's 2 now. Then we release the `countDownController`. So later in `viewWillDisappear` when I try to empty the array to release the retained `MainViewControllers` in it, my app crashes!?

Comment: I am not sure I understand: you say that if you empty the array in `viewWillDisappear` your app crashes. Could you post the crash you have?

Comment: I mean when I add a view controller to the viewControllers array it gets retained by the array. So how to do I make the array release its member object memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for you if you don't want to use `UIPageViewController` (read my other answer).

The sample project is designed for a constant number of pages (`kNumberOfPages`). The scrollview content size and the size of the view controller array depends on the number of pages. The sample code set this up in awakeFromNib, which is called only once.

So in order to make this dynamic you could recreate the whole ContentController when the number of pages changes. You just need to add a property for the number of pages.

The other option would be to reset the scrollview and view controller array when the number of pages changes.

I'm assuming you have defined a property for the events:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray* eventsArray;
```

You could then add a setter method like this:

```
-(void)setEventsArray:(NSArray *)eventsArray
{
    if (eventsArray != _eventsArray) {
        [_eventsArray release];
        _eventsArray = [eventsArray retain];
        NSUInteger eventCount = [eventsArray count];
        //reset scrollview contentSize
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * eventCount, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        // reset content offset to zero
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

        //remove all subviews
        [[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

        pageControl.numberOfPages = eventCount;

        // reset viewcontroller array
        NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < eventCount; i++)
        {
            [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
        self.viewControllers = controllers;
        [controllers release];

        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];
    }
}
```

You call this method from the table view controller at the time when the user switches to the scroll view.

Comment: That's all interesting but I already modified the Apple PageControl code to allow arbitrary number of pages and I'm already having a separate data model to get the number of pages from. So my code works but I'm having a problem with memory although I'm releasing the view controllers when the scroll view disappears. And I don't see how your code solves this memory problem.

Comment: You empty the scroll view and the view controller array and still have living view controller instances? Then there must be some more strong references to the MainViewControllers. Check if dealloc is called in MainViewController.

Comment: Yes. dealloc is never called in any MainViewController instance even when I release them, but I really dunno why.

Comment: Oh a small note: I'm not emptying the view controllers array. How do i do that properly? I tried something that made the app crash. So I'm open to the proper way of doing that.

Comment: Did you try my solution? I'm resetting the array with NSNull objects.

Comment: Yes. Actually in the `viewWillAppear' method I have this code that sets the events array to Null. I put it in the question.

Comment: I'm trying to implement you code but I have a separate dataModel controller for the eventsArray. So in this case where should I call the above set events array in my scrollViewController code? I tried awakeFromNib and you are right it gets called only once. So I tried viewWillAppear and I have the memory problem explained above. The first 2 viewControllers are always created new and never get released cuz viewWillAppear will be called always and I have these 2 lines there `[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];`. Thanx

Comment: I also have this `NSInteger kNumberOfPages;` just before `@interface` then I initialize it to the number of events in viewWillAppear like this `kNumberOfPages = [self.dataModel occasionCount];` but I'm suspicious cuz in Apple's code it's static and it's NSUInteger not NSInteger. Thank you so much for your help. I have awarded you the 50 points of the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's PageControl sample code is 2 years old and you can consider it as deprecated because there is a new container view controller in iOS 5 that does all this: `UIPageViewController`.

You should really start using `UIPageViewController`, then you don't need that loadScrollViewWithPage method at all. It would be less code and more easy.

Take a look at the [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller) sample code. It has been updated to take full advantage of `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Fine answer, however the scrolling transition style of `UIPageViewController` is iOS 6 only. If he wants to target iOS 5, that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are implementing Apple's [View Controller Containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) pratices. It would make memory management that much easier and safer.

Plus, hoping that it might save you a lot of future headaches, there is already an open source project that does what you are describing (implementing a self-managing scrollview of an arbritary number of view controllers).

You might want to take a look at it: [RHHorizontalSwipe](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHHorizontalSwipe).

Comment: I read the view controller containment practices page. I'm using the scroll view controller as a container view controller and it is responsible of pushing new child view controllers and releasing them. I don't know what is specifically with my code above that won't release the child view controllers memory properly.

Comment: Where are you calling `removeFromParentViewController` then?

Comment: In the 2nd code chunk above int he question under the viewWillDisappear of my container scroll view I'm doing so: `[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Comment: But that's just it... with that line you are simply removing the view from the view hierarchy and not the view controller itself, which stays allocated in memory. If you are already using view controller containment, then when you send a `removeFromParentViewController` message to one of the childs it will be effectively deallocated shortly after. Please try to understand the reasons why `removeFromParentViewController` is very different from `removeFromSuperview` (besides one being a `UIViewController` method and the other a `UIView` method). Apple's documentation is very clear on that.

Comment: That's interesting and makes sense. But when I tried `removeFromParentViewController` instead of `removeFromSuperview` the app crashed! Is `viewWillDisAppear` the wrong place to call it?

Comment: Here is a recording of how the app works http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5W8v_smZSog

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a UIScrollView containing multiple UIViewController views sounds sketchy at best, that design does not sound good at all.

That being said, one potential issue could be this line:

```
if ((NSNull *)countdownController == [NSNull null])
```

You would be better off with something like this:

```
if (!countdownController || [countdownController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Also, you should call `[super viewWillDisappear:animated]` in your `viewWillDisappear` method.