# NSMutableArray of viewControllers not releasing the memory of its objects

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray, viewcontroller

This is basically related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118926/releasing-memory-of-multiple-view-controllers-inside-a-scrollview)

I'm trying to release the `NSMutableArray` which contains viewControllers. I do:

```
self.viewControllers = nil;
```

In `viewWillDisappear` because I'm moving to another view. But no matter what I do the view Controllers are not released. I also tried:

```
[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Where scrollview is the view owning the containing `NSMutableArray`.

I see the count of live view controllers (in instruments) not changing although the reference count of the containing `NSMutableArray` is 0.

Comment: When you say "reference count", I assume you mean the "retain count"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Make sure you run your non-ARC code through the static analyzer. This can find many memory management issues that plague non-ARC code. Select "Analyze" from the "Product" menu in Xcode, or press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. A lot of these memory management issues go away if you use ARC, but if you're not using ARC, the static analyzer can be invaluable in examining your code.
2. Your attempt to `removeFromSuperview` is unnecessary, and would not affect the `retainCount` of the view controllers, themselves. Do I infer from this attempt, though, that you've created view controllers and then added their views to the scroll view? If so, did you do the necessary `addChildViewController` for each of those? If so, you do need to do the associated `removeFromParentViewController` for each of those, though.
3. The proper deallocation of the view controllers is a function of how you defined and allocated the `viewControllers` array, and how you populated it.

   But, for example, I have a property:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
   ```

   And I initialized it with the following code (note the `autorelease` of the `NSMutableArray` itself (since I'm using the accessor method which will retain it for me), and the explicit `release` of the `Object` objects):

   ```
   - (void)makeArray
   {
       // create an array, using the accessor method (thus why I'm using an autorelease object)

       self.array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

       // just add four random objects to the array.
       // note, adding them to the array increases their retain count, thus I 
       // release them to bring the retain count back to +1 ... I could have 
       // done that via autorelease, too

       for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 4; i++)
       {
           Object *obj = [[Object alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d", i]];
           [self.array addObject:obj];
           [obj release];
       }
   }
   ```

   If I examine the `retainCount` values, I can see that everything has a `retainCount` of +1, as is appropriate:

   ```
   - (void)logArray
   {
       // let's examine the retain counts for the objects in the array
       // should be "1" given there are no other strong references anywhere

       for (id obj in self.array)
           NSLog(@"%s %@ (retainCount = %d)", __FUNCTION__, obj, [obj retainCount]);

       // let's also examine the retain count for the array, itself
       // this should also be "1"

       NSLog(@"%s retainCount = %d", __FUNCTION__, [self.array retainCount]);
   }
   ```

   It (and the array's individual objects) are properly deallocated when I clear it in the following method (a fact verified by the fact that the `Object` class does a `NSLog` during its `dealloc` method):

   ```
   - (void)clearArray
   {
       // let's use the accessor method to release the array and make sure
       // the pointer is nil

       self.array = nil;
   }
   ```
4. This is all a long-winded way of saying that your syntax of `self.viewControllers = nil;` is a perfectly suitable way to release the array (and thus its member objects), assuming the array is defined as a `retain` property as illustrated in the previous point. But, if the array's member objects are not getting released, then those objects are obviously not getting their `retainCount` down to zero. I would try, right before your `self.viewControllers = nil;`, logging not only the `retainCount` of the array itself, but also the `retainCount` of the individual objects of your array, to confirm their `retainCount` settings.

   They should all have a `retainCount` of +1 at that point (otherwise there is something else retaining them, either because they've been over-retained, you have some retain cycle (a.k.a. strong reference cycle) in those view controllers, or something else is legitimately retaining them (e.g. at some point you pushed one of those view controllers onto the navigator stack, but you haven't yet popped them off)).
5. If you're still leaking, I would then use Instruments to [find the leak](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4). By the way, when examine the call tree for leaks, I find it useful to "Invert Call Tree" and to "Hide System Libraries".

---

**Update:**

Above, in point 4, I warn of the risk of retain cycles. An example of a retain cycle is the use of a `NSTimer` by the view controller and a failure to `invalidate` and `release` the timer when it's time to release the view controller. Chatting with you offline, this sounds like this may be the issue, where you were trying to `release` the `NSTimer` in `dealloc`, but the `dealloc` will never called because the timer, itself, is retaining the view controller. You need to manually `invalidate` and `release` the `NSTimer` (there by releasing the strong reference to the view controller) for any view controllers that have timers before you release the `NSMutableArray`. (E.g. maybe have a protocol for stopping timers, make your child view controllers conform to that.)

Comment: @Ali I was thinking about why you were doing that `removeFromSuperview` stuff, and was wondering if you were adding the view controller's views to the subviews, and if so, if you did the necessary `addChildViewController` too. If so, you have to do the associated `removeFromParentViewController` when you're cleaning up. See point 2 of my updated answer.

Comment: 1. I did use the static analyzer and there are no problems.

Comment: 2. Yes I'm creating the view controller and then adding its view as a subview like this `[scrollView addSubview:countdownController.view];` Please check my original question linked in the question above. 3. I populate the array like this: `NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    [controllers release];`   4. I'll try to check the retain count of the array objects.

Comment: 4. Again. Yes the retain count for `viewControllers` array objects is 2 for each of them. But I really dunno where this extra retain comes form. Could you please check my original question and provide some helpful hints? Than you so much. The thing is in Instruments I see only 2 living `viewController` objects if the array has 2 controllers for example. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ali Yeah, I saw that original question, but the unfortunate reality is that you're not showing us any code that would do the additional retain, so we can't help you unless you share more code. In your answer to #2, you show us how you use the controller's view, but you don't show us all the references to the controllers (besides adding it to the array), and thus we can't see what's retaining it.

Comment: I'd again suggest, though, that you run this through Leaks tool in Instruments (e.g. when you Profile the app). This may well show you precisely what is retaining your view controllers. Or you can manually identify those things that could possibly retain it (i.e. look at everything where the view controller, itself, is a parameter to a method). But your answer to #4, where you note that the retain count is 2 is the root of the problem, so you have to somehow identify what's doing that additional retain (such as `addChildViewController`, using recurring `NSTimer`, etc.).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19397/discussion-between-rob-and-ali)

Comment: Yes. It was a retain cycle created by the NSTimer used in the view controllers. Your update to the question is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard for us to diagnose, given the details provided. However, you can quickly diagnose this yourself by running Instruments (e.g. Leaks). If configured accordingly, it can:

- point out retain cycles
- record all reference count operations
- and/or you can use heapshot analysis

Once you get the hang of these tools, the time it takes to isolate such issues should (typically) be reduced to a few minutes.

Comment: I did all of that. Please check my original question linked in the question above. Now it comes down to releasing the `viewControllers` retained by the `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a quick test:

```
- (void) test
{
    NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    // MyViewController is your view controller class
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil]; // add autorelease if you aren't using ARC
    [testArray addObject:vc];

    // On exit, testArray will be released, so will vc
}
```

Set a breakpoint on dealloc in MyViewController and check if it's called. If it is called then, and not in your code, it means that your view controllers are being retained somewhere, and you'll have to find where are they retained.

Comment: I did the test and with `autorelease` it does release the `viewController` and calls dealloc. I'm not using ARC but I don't wanna use `autorelease` I wanna release te `viewController` in the time of my choosing and that is when the scroll's `viewWillDisappear'.

Comment: If you didn't create your view controllers with autorelease before adding them to self.viewControllers, then the viewControllers have a +2 retain count (+1 for alloc/initWithNibName, +1 for addObject in NSMutableArray). If you only release the array with self.viewControllers = nil, the view controllers in self.viewControllers still have a retain count of +1, so they will never be released. In order to release them, you can [self.viewControllers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(release)] before self.viewControllers = nil;